# rails app fails to start: <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails 2.3.9 app won't start, this is what happens:

```
C:\Devel\immonatie>ruby script/server
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
script/../config/boot (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

The app was working great. My development machine is a windows machine. I changed the environment. I was using the Bitnami RubyStack. Now I removed it and installed the package from rubyinstaller.org. The environment seems to work, I was able to install gems.
For this app to work, something still seems to be missing. But the error message is not helping me.

Anybody an idea where I should look?

Comment: Can you post your `config/environment.rb`? Did you update your script/* stuff after upgrading rails?